# How to plot categorical variables with a pie chart

Tags: pandas, visualization, dataframe, matplotlib, distribution

I am concerned with a single column (`fruit`) from my `df`:

```
| fruit               |
| --------------------|  
| apple, orange       | 
| banana              |
| grapefruit, orange  |
| apple, banana, kiwi |
```

I want to plot the values from `fruit` to a pie chart to get a visual representation of the distribution of each individual fruit

I run: `df.plot(kind='pie', y='fruit')`

But this gives a `TypeError`: `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I have read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

But I can't see how it helps solve my problem

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want first to try to count the number of occurrences of each string inside the column, and from then you have only to plot with whatever kind of plot you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"fruit":["apple, orange", "banana", "grapefruit, orange", "apple, banana, kiwi"]})

df.fruit.str.get_dummies(sep = ",").sum().plot.pie();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `value_counts()` and then plot the returned series like this:

```
df["col_name"].value_counts().plot.pie()
```